# How to implement PersistAuth which refetch the context on page reload using React ReduxToolkit (RTK Query)

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a react app that has **PersistAuth**, and  **RequireAuth** which I implemented using ContextApi. Now I'm building another application but want to implement everything in React using ReduxToolkit. The first step is Authentication which I have already done successfully. The only thing left is how to keep the login state persistent upon page refresh or page reload.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your login state persistent when using Redux Toolkit, you can use a library called "redux-persist." It's like a magical box that stores your app's data, including whether a user is logged in, even when the page is refreshed or reloaded.

Here's what you do:

Install Redux Persist: First, install the "redux-persist" library in your project.- npm install redux-persist or yarn add redux-persist

Create a Persist Configuration: In your store configuration file (usually store.js), you'll configure redux-persist. You'll want to import persistReducer from redux-persist and the storage you want to use (usually localStorage)

Wrap Your App: Wrap your entire app with a special component provided by Redux Persist. This component ensures that when you start your app, it checks the "magic box" (where your data is stored) and brings back the login state, so the user doesn't have to log in again after a page refresh.

Comment: Saving the state is not the actual question here. My scenario is when the user refreshes the page,  a token is sent to the server, server decodes the token, and resend another token in the response along with the user.